# Using Directive/Isolated scope as HTML inside a angular-bootstrap popover

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Using [angular-ui popover](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover) you can put an html inside a popover. If for example I have a directive named **sampleDirective** (assuming this directive exists) how can I put it inside the popover? I tried using `$sce.trustAsHtml` but it doesn't work. I also tried `$compile` but failed miserably.

```
$sce.trustAsHtml('<sample-directive></sample-directive>');
```

Is there a way to use to put an element directive inside a popover?

Comment: You have the `uib-popover-template` attribute - So you can try put it there, but as the documentation state: _Note that the contents of this template need to be wrapped in a tag, e.g., <div></div>_

Comment: Thanks @AlonEitan! It worked..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by Alon Eitan, instead of using `ui-popover-html`, I used `ui-popover-template` instead and directed the templateUrl of the directive to it.. In this case, there is no need of an isolated scope anymore..